# Access layout TextView without data binding or findViewById()?

Tags: android, kotlin

Currently learning Android programming and more specifically Kotlin (and MVVM) I was wondering how to access the TextView of my activity's layout.

Indeed, I saw that there are two very well known ways to do this, either with a findViewById() or with data binding.

I was amazed that I could change the text in a TextView by doing neither (at least that's what I think, I'm probably wrong).

You will find below the code of my activity where I modify the text of my TextView in never make a findViewById and without ever creating a binding object in the setupView() function.

```
class MovieDetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MovieDetailViewModel;

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_detail)

        val movieId = intent.getIntExtra("id",1) //TODO : ne plus mettre un id de film en brut mais celui qui sera cliqué sur la page home
        val apiService : TMDBInterface = TMDBClient.getClient()

        viewModel = getViewModel(apiService,movieId)

        viewModel.movieDetails.observe(this, Observer {
            setupView(it)
        })

        viewModel.networkState.observe(this, Observer {
            activity_movie_detail_progress_bar.visibility = if (it == NetworkState.LOADING) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
            activity_movie_detail_error_text_view.visibility = if (it == NetworkState.ERROR) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        })
    }

    fun setupView(movie : MovieDetails){
        this.activity_movie_detail_title_text_view.text = movie.title
        this.activity_movie_detail_overview_text_view.text = movie.overview
        this.activity_movie_detail_release_text_view.text = movie.releaseDate
        this.activity_movie_detail_vote_average_text_view.text = movie.voteAverage.toString()
        this.activity_movie_detail_vote_number_text_view.text = movie.voteCount.toString()

        val formatCurrencey = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE)
        activity_movie_detail_budget_text_view.text = formatCurrencey.format(movie.budget)

        val moviePosterURL = POSTER_BASE_URL + movie.posterPath
        Glide.with(this)
            .load(moviePosterURL)
            .into(activity_movie_detail_scrollview_image_view)
    }

    /*
    Méthode qui créer notre ViewModel
    Ayant besoin de paramètres, on doit utiliser une ViewModel Factory et overide la méthode create
    */
    private fun getViewModel(apiService:TMDBInterface, movieId:Int): MovieDetailViewModel {
        return ViewModelProviders.of(this, object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                return MovieDetailViewModel(apiService,movieId) as T
            }
        })[MovieDetailViewModel::class.java]
    }
}
```

You will also find the XML layout file below of my activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".presentation.activities.movieDetailActivity.MovieDetailActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/activity_movie_detail_progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activity_movie_detail_error_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/connection_problem"
            android:visibility="gone"
        />
        <ScrollView
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_movie_detail_scrollview_linear_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/activity_movie_detail_scrollview_image_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="500dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:scaleType="matrix"
                />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/activity_movie_detail_info_linear_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/activity_movie_detail_title_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                    />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/activity_movie_detail_overview_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="italic"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/activity_movie_detail_info_complement_linear_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/activity_movie_detail_release_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/releaseDate"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/activity_movie_detail_vote_average_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/vote_average"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/activity_movie_detail_vote_number_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/vote_number"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/activity_movie_detail_budget_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/budget"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                    />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I just want to know how it was possible to access without the 2 methods?

EDIT: Thanks to EraftYps & René's answer, I know it's **Kotlin synthetics**

Comment: It's called Kotlin synthetics. What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the properties of a `TextView` like its *text*, you need a reference to the `TextView` directly or indirectly.

To get a reference to the `TextView` you need to either use `ViewBinding`, `DataBinding`, `findViewById()` or its sibling functions like `findViewByTag()`.

You can also use `Kotlin Synthetics`, as you do in your example, and in my opinion, this is not a good practice because of the reasons explained in [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/the-argument-over-kotlin-synthetics-735305dd4ed0).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and for the link.

I'll read it and surely change the way I do it to avoid bad practice !

Thanks !